# Specify lenient SOAP parsing with CXF in Grails

Tags: grails, cxf

We're using CXF in Grails to call to another web service via SOAP. The service side has additional elements, but no changes to existing ones. I'd like the client side side to be able to work with the new service, simply ignoring the new fields and parsing the ones it already was. Is there some flag or something we can set to tell it to ignore extra elements/attributes/fields?

I found some posts that said to `set "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" to "false"` but I have tried to do that in Config.groovy but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

After more googling and experimentation I figured it out:

```
cxf {
    ...
    client {
        clientName {
            // ...
            requestContext = ['set-jaxb-validation-event-handler':  false]
```